# Can llvm execute code from managed languages?

Tags: python, c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm making an application and I would like to load and execute llvm bitcode using the ExecutionEngine. I have managed to do this with really simple C code compiled via clang so far.

My thought is, if I use llvm for this project then it could be more language agnostic than say, specifically picking lua/python/javascript. But I'm confused about how this might work for managed or scripting languages since they are often times tied to a platform with resources such as a GC. So I'm not sure how it would actually work through the ExecutionEngine.

So as an example scenario, suppose a user wanted to write some python code that runs in my application. I then want them to deliver to me bitcode representing that python code, which I will then run in my C++ application using llvm's ExecutionEngine.

Is this possible? Can python be simply compiled into bitcode and then run later using the ExecutionEngine? If not, what do I need to know to understand why not?

Comment: LLVM in this case is not any different from a mere `dlopen`.

Comment: So python would have to compile in everything it needed to run, including the GC, into the bitcode? It could do this? Does it actually do this?

Comment: There is no technical obstacle to compiling Python (or any other language) to LLVM bitcode. It's just very unlikely there's an existing compiler.

Comment: numba is a LLVM compiler. But not a big part of the python library is supported yet.

Comment: You'll need a python runtime anyway. It's possible to compile the whole python runtime into a single bitcode module, of course, but I see no point in it, it's not any different from embedding the python interpreter the usual way.

Comment: @delnan: there is ;-) Python runs nicely on PNaCl

Comment: @EliBendersky A Python bytecode compiler and interpreter running under PNaCl is not the same as a Python compiler emitting LLVM code. Both might solve OP's use case just fine, but I only claimed one of the two is unlikely to exist ;-)

Comment: @delnan: I also don't know whether the other one exists. Unladen Swallow tried to do that, but ultimately failed.

Comment: So what I'm understanding is that you could compile the python runtime into bitcode, run that, which would then read and run your .py scripts like normal?

I guess this is essentially how you could get your platform of choice running on PNaCL right?
https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading and some conversations I believe the answer is that the ExecutionEngine essentially executes code as if it was native C code. Which means if you wanted to execute lua/python/javascript code ontop of llvm you would need to actually send the bitcode for that runtime. Then the runtime could parse and execute the script as usual.

As far as I know none of these runtimes have the ability to compile their script directly into llvm bitcode (yet).